# Deletar chave composta de uma tabela com angular e asp.net core

Tags: c#, angular, mvc, asp.net-core, chave-composta

E ai pessoal tudo tranquilo? seguinte estou com problemas com chave composta no meu projeto e queria a ajuda de vocês pois ainda não sei muito bem a respeito, estou fazendo o front em Angular e o backend com Asp.net core mvc (usando web API), basicamente o projeto é um CRUD, já consigo listar ele bonitinho porém não consigo deletar, ele sempre me apresenta um erro.

Aqui está o delete no controller:

```
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Access>> DeleteAccess(string Entity, decimal SystemCode)
        {
            var access = await _context.Access.FindAsync(Entity, SystemCode);

            if (access == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Access.Remove(access);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return access;
        }
```

Não sei se está correto, se realmente é assim que passa a chave composta (no caso as chaves compostas são **Entity** e **SystemCode**).

E no Angular eu fiz o seguinte, no HTML eu coloquei um botão onde o `(click)` dele eu passo um método chamado `delete` para um parâmetro chamado `row`, vejam abaixo:

```
<button [tooltip]="'Delete Access'" (click)="delete(row)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-color" type="button" [tooltipAppendToBody]><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Já no component eu fiz o seguinte no meu método:

```
  delete(row) {
    this.accessService.delete(row.Entity)
    .then(data => this.getAll());
  }
```

Sei que meu component está faltando passar o **SystemCode** no delete mas eu não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso.

No navegador quando vejo no console ele passa esse erro:

```
DELETE http://localhost:52434/access/teste 404 (Not Found)

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found","url":"http://localhost:52434/access/teste","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:52434/access/teste: 404 Not Found","error":{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4","title":"Not Found","status":404,"traceId":"|924b0f7-47c01b3e49c595d5."}}
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:836)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at zone.js:897
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27338)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:430)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:198)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:611)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:517)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1671)
```

Alguém pode auxiliar este pobre estagiário a solucionar este problema? hahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom senhores, consegui solucionar e vou deixar minha contribuição aqui para quem estiver com o mesmo erro ;D

Basicamente o backend estava correto, tendo apenas que alterar o `id` para `Entity`, pois o mesmo estava retornando ERRO 404, ou seja, não estava encontrando o caminho. Apenas mudei:

```
de [HttpDelete("{id}")], para [HttpDelete("{Entity}")]
```

Então o backend ficou:

```
        [HttpDelete("{Entity}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Access>> DeleteAccess(string Entity, decimal SystemCode)
        {
            var access = await _context.Access.FindAsync(Entity, SystemCode);

            if (access == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Access.Remove(access);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return access;
        }
```

Tranquilo, backend solucionado! agora como ficou o frontend? como passei as chaves compostas? fiz o seguinte:

```
  delete(row) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('SystemCode', row.SystemCode);
    this.accessService.delete(row.Entity, `Do you want to remove?`, params)
      .then(data => this.getAll());
  }
```

no delete eu apenas utilizei o `HttpParams` passando a outra `row` que eu precisava ;D